# Magento creating new product with self-created attributes and options

Tags: php, api, magento, attributes, product

Similar questions here didn't helped me with my problem, so I'll just ask by myself.

I've got a php file which creates an attribute (Drop-Down) and a php file which creates options for it.

Now I want to create a php file which generates me a simple product for magento with one or more attributes (which were created before)

Here's my piece of code to generate the data for it:

```
$code = "\$newProductData = array(  
          " . ((!empty($name)) ? "'name' => '$name', " : "") . "
          " . ((!empty($websites)) ? "'websites' => '$websites[0]', " : "") . "
          " . ((!empty($description)) ? "'description' => '$description', " : "") . "
          " . ((!empty($description_short)) ? "'description_short' => '$description_short', " : "") . "
          " . ((!empty($price)) ? "'price' => '$price', " : "") . "
          " . ((!empty($type)) ? "'type' => '$type', " : "") . "
          " . ((!empty($status)) ? "'status' => '$status', " : "") . "
          " . ((!empty($weight)) ? "'weight' => '$weight', " : "") . "
          " . ((!empty($tax_class_id)) ? "'tax_class_id' => '$tax_class_id', " : "") . "
          " . ((!empty($categories)) ? "'categories' => '$categories', " : "") . "
          " . ((!empty($manufacturer)) ? "'manufacturer' => '$manufacturer', " : "") . "
          " . ((!empty($color)) ? "'color' => '$color', " : "") . "
          " . ((!empty($url_key)) ? "'url_key' => '$url_key', " : "") . "
          " . ((!empty($url_path)) ? "'url_path' => '$url_path', " : "") . "
          " . ((!empty($visibility)) ? "'visibility' => '$visibility', " : "") . "
          " . ((!empty($news_from_date)) ? "'news_from_date' => '$news_from_date', " : "") . "
          " . ((!empty($news_to_date)) ? "'news_to_date' => '$news_to_date', " : "") . "
          " . ((!empty($special_price)) ? "'special_price' => '$special_price', " : "") . "
          " . ((!empty($special_from_date)) ? "'special_from_date' => '$special_from_date', " : "") . "
          " . ((!empty($special_to_date)) ? "'special_to_date' => '$special_to_date', " : "") . "
          " . ((!empty($meta_title)) ? "'meta_title' => '$meta_title', " : "") . "
          " . ((!empty($meta_keyword)) ? "'meta_keyword' => '$meta_keyword', " : "") . "
          " . ((!empty($meta_description)) ? "'meta_description' => '$meta_description', " : "") . "
          " . ((!empty($enable_googlecheckout)) ? "'enable_googlecheckout' => '$enable_googlecheckout', " : "") . "
          " . ((!empty($custom_design)) ? "'custom_design' => '$custom_design', " : "") . "
          " . ((!empty($custom_design_from)) ? "'custom_design_from' => '$custom_design_from', " : "") . "
          " . ((!empty($custom_design_to)) ? "'custom_design_to' => '$custom_design_to', " : "") . "
          " . ((!empty($custom_layout_update)) ? "'custom_layout_update' => '$custom_layout_update', " : "") . "
          " . ((!empty($page_layout)) ? "'page_layout' => '$page_layout', " : "") . "
          " . ((!empty($old_id)) ? "'old_id' => '$old_id', " : "") . "
          " . ((!empty($required_options)) ? "'required_options' => '$required_options', " : "") . "
          " . ((!empty($has_options)) ? "'has_options' => '$has_options', " : "") . "
          " . ((!empty($image_label)) ? "'image_label' => '$image_label', " : "") . "
          " . ((!empty($small_image_label)) ? "'small_image_label' => '$small_image_label', " : "") . "
          " . ((!empty($thumbnail_label)) ? "'thumbnail_label' => '$thumbnail_label', " : "") . "
          " . ((!empty($gift_message_available)) ? "'gift_message_available' => '$gift_message_available', " : "") . "
          " . ((!empty($cost)) ? "'cost' => '$cost', " : "") . "
          " . ((!empty($is_in_stock)) ? "'is_in_stock' => '$is_in_stock', " : "") . "
          " . ((!empty($qty)) ? "'qty' => '$qty', " : "") . "
          " . ((!empty($minimal_price)) ? "'minimal_price' => '$minimal_price', " : "") . "
          " . ((!empty($tier_price)) ? "'tier_price' => '$tier_price', " : "") . "
          " . ((!empty($options_container)) ? "'options_container' => '$options_container', " : "") . "
       );";

      /* evaluate code */
      eval($code);

      /* cause i dunno if i could simple add the attributes under the evaluated code, i'm merging  each attribute to main array with product data like productdata = (array)productdata + (array)attributeX */
     /* $attributes[$iteration] = "myattributename like custommanufacturer" */
     /* $attributeoptions[$iteration] = "myoptionname like customname" */
      while($iteration != $attr_count -1)
      {
        $iteration++;
        $attributeData = array($attributes[$iteration] => $attributeoptions[$iteration]);
        $newProductData = array_merge((array)$newProductData,(array)$attributeData);
      }
    if ($proxy->create($type, $set['set_id'], $sku, $newProductData)) 
      {
          $hp_bereich .= "\nsuccess=yes";
          $hp_bereich .= "\nwarning=";
          $hp_bereich .= "\nerrorcode=0";
          $hp_bereich .= "\nSKU=" .$sku;
      } 
      else 
      {
          $hp_bereich .= "\nsuccess=no";
          $hp_bereich .= "\nwarning=Error creating product see scriptblock";
          $hp_bereich .= "\nerrorcode=-2001";
          $hp_bereich .= "\nSKU=" .$sku;
      }
```

Now here's the problem:
Product creating : done perfectly
Attribute will be shown on Admin-Panel inside of the Product (Drop-Down with selected Option for it): nope.

Could anyone help me with this problem?

I must create a product from scratch (with few information) including attributes which will be created by the user who's controlling/filling the php-file with information.

Comment: well i've just noticed that my custom generated attribute was not added to default attributeset (must edit my php for it). Now it the Drop-Down from my Custom Attribute will be shown but not the Option which has been set by generating the product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, and most importantly, do not use `eval`. It's too risky and could allow code injection, if just one of those many variables wasn't properly validated it could contain attacking code. There is a reason many web hosts disable it completely. In this case there is no benefit to `eval`, it achieves nothing you cannot do otherwise.

---

To make a simple product is very simple indeed.

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->setTypeId('simple')
    ->setWebsiteIds($websites)
    ->setName($name)
    ->setDescription($description)
    ->setDescriptionShort($description_short)
    // etc...
    ->save();
```

The setters are magic methods so you can use any attribute name you like. If the value passed is null the attribute is unset so it is safe to call all those setters unconditionally. If you are building those variables from an array - perhaps using [`extract()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) - then it is quicker to use the array directly:

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->setTypeId('simple')
    ->addData($array)
    ->save();
```

---

If you want to learn how an existing product stores it's attributes use something like the following:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
print_r($product->debug());
```

This is a good debugging technique and reveals a lot. Do this to find how the drop-down attributes are stored.

Comment: first of all, thanks for the "eval"-information, so this "magic"-Methods would to something like : setMyspecialattribute if its named "myspecialattribute"? what about underscores like "my_special_attribute"? do i have to set the name of the option for it or the id? i will check the debug function to get more informations. Thank you

Comment: Good point about the underscores; they are turned into camel case. `my_special_attribute` becomes `setMySpecialAttribute()` and `getMySpecialAttribute()`.

Comment: When an attribute is a drop-down then you set and get it's option ID. Finally to get the value you must use the slightly clumsy `$product->getAttributeText('my_special_attribute')`. This time it is not a magic method and there is no "set" equivalent.

Comment: thanks for the "technical term" camelcase :D well i just need to transfer the value (or id) of the option into the product so that the dropdown looks like : DropDownAttribute --> 1. me 2. you 3. us 4. we   for getting the id / value back from it i've got a function already. Thank you so much, will write if i've got any problems after or if it works ;)

Comment: sorry for the annoying questions but is it possible (php4 compatible, dunno if the info is important) to write something like this :            $_product->set .$camelcasedattribute -> $attributoptionid   ?

Comment: Luckily there is a function just for that. `$product->setData($attributeName, $attributeOptionId);`

Comment: *.* thank you so much, saved my day. do i need the camelcased attributename for $attributeName or the originally name like "my_special_attribute"?

Comment: Thanks for the function ->setData and the informations, but is it possible to "setData" directly after creation time in the same php file? in my php file i create the product (thanks to your code) but i didn't have any object from it or any productId to get the Product itself.

Comment: Those function chains both return the product object so you can insert `->setData()` in the chain before the final save, or assign the whole lot to `$product`. Most functions in Magento return themselves so that chaining is possible (except getters obviously, they return the value they are getting).